# Is there a way to differentiate the statuscode 401 of a page pre authentification and after closing the promtp?

Tags: apache, http-status-code-401

so i have a webpage with a login section. Login is done with .htaccess and .htpasswd file. That works fine. Now i need to style or customize the "unauthorized" page that results after closing the authentification prompt.

Here is my problem: If I request the page, .htaccess kicks in and wants me to authenticate, resulting in a status code of 401. But if I close the promt, I get the "Unauthorized
This server could not verify that you are authorized..." response with an status code of also 401 back.

Question: Is there a way to differentiate the statuscode 401 of a page pre authentification and after closing the promtp?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_auth_form.html) for this.

perhaps also set the 401 document

```
ErrorDocument 401 "/login.shtml"
```

Comment: thx but checked the documentation already and didn't find a solution there.